# In a View-Based Application, concerning editing the .xib window in the Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface, builder

So I just started programming in X-Code/Objective-C recently.

I know how to put objects (like textboxes, pictures, etc.) on the .xib file.

So, when I actually run the application how can I make it so when I click a button a whole new set of objects appear and the older ones disappear? (For example new text boxes, inserted pictures, etc.)

Can I just stick with using one .xib file or should I make a call to another .xib file?  Would I have to edit code in some way to acheive this?

Thanks,

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

The use of Target-Action will work...It's not practical, but yes you can build a full blown application with just Interface Builder.

For a window (NSWindow) you can use these actions...

makeKeyAndOrderFront - Brings a window to the front of the window list and makes it the key window

orderFront - Brings a window to the front of the window list

orderOut - Takes the window out of the window list

Assuming you are using the same xml nib file (xib), you can add a window and add a button to that window. Add other windows and set them to not be visible at launch (uncheck visible at launch). Ctrl drag from the button to your windows selecting the desired action.

Good luck

Comment: so to use the Target-Action.. how would you use it? Do you have to edit the code? If so which code file should I edit?

Comment: so to use the Target-Action.. how would you use it? Do you have to edit the code? If so which code file should I edit?

Comment: In Interface builder for your xib file click on a button then open up the Connection Inspector. Under Sent Actions you can click and drag to a Received Action of another object. In the code you normally setup an IBAction and then link the button to that action.